# How do i export a database in ubuntu to specified location using terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, mysql

I get a blank screen since i have installed the ATI graphic drivers. I tried a lot of things restore my laptop but all in vain. Only formatting seems to be the other option.

So i want to export my databases to a specified location i.e /media/mount/d using the terminal.

How do i do it ..please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /media/mount/d
mysqldump -u {user} -p {database} > {database}.sql
```

and all you need to supply is the password for {user}.